# Ruby: cgi + ssh doesn't work together

Tags: ruby, ssh, cgi

Can't force 'cgi' and 'ssh' modules to work together. For example, this piece of code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9

require 'cgi'
require 'net/ssh'

cgi = CGI.new

cgi.out("status" => "302", "Connection" => "close", "Content-Length" => 1, "Location" => 'http://google.com') {' '}

2.times { |t| %x[ echo 'do something #{t}' >> /tmp/log.log ] }

%x[ echo 'before ssh' >> /tmp/log.log ]

Net::SSH.start('somehost.domain', 'someuser', :keys => [ "/tmp/id_rsa" ]) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec("echo 'doing some job on remote host'; sleep 5")
end

%x[ echo 'after ssh' >> /tmp/log.log ]
```

produces the following output to /tmp/log when run under web-server (notice absence of output after ssh-session begins):

```
do something 0
do something 1
before ssh
```

When I run in from shell it executes entirely as I expected:

```
do something 0
do something 1
before ssh
after ssh
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using CGI? Why not use something a LOT more modern, like, at a minimum, [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) or talk directly to [Rack](http://rack.github.io/)?

Comment: Also, instead of relying on repeatedly opening sub-shells to redirect the output of echo commands, why not use Ruby's built-in Logger, or open the logging file using `File.open` with an `a` mode so you append to it? As is, your code is highly inefficient and going against the flow.

Comment: Finally, your code runs as you when you run it from the shell. It runs as the web-server owner, which *should* have reduced privileges, when it runs as a CGI. That might preclude using SSH, or resources it needs.

Comment: 1. I choosed cgi because script supposed to be very simple (almost like in my exapmle) and use Rack or framework for it is just overkill. But it seems it have no choise.
2. Logging via shell is just for example. Of corse I'm using logger.
3. Privileges are not the case - I run script from the same user who runs web-server.